# In an MVC razor view with a layout, how do I compensate in the body if the header expands?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

When adding an additional line of display in the header, the expanded header overlays the body.  It doesn't seem that straightforward to compensate for this since the bootstrap does all of the styling behind the scenes.

This is the normal view:

[image]

When the expanded header is displayed, you can see a line of the body is overlaid.

[image]

In the second picture, a line of the body is overlaid.  What do I need to do to compensate for the expanded header?  I would like to be able to compensate for a variable sized header rather than just add < br/ > elements which will only work for a specific sized header.

**Razor page code as requested in comment:**

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                @<div Class="navbar-text navbar-left">
                    @Model.HelpTitle <br /> @Model.Message
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)
</body>
```

In the code above, the difference between a single line or double line display in the header is dependent on these 2 fields.

```
@Model.HelpTitle
@Model.Message
```

If there is no `message`, then there is a single line.  If there is a `message`, then there are 2 lines and the header expands down into the body.

I don't understand the 2nd comment below to use relative position, so if someone could explain, that would be great.

Comment: Add padding to the top of the body,  but share your code html/css so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Adding padding will not solve the problem. Position should be relative so that when the deader comes down the body also comes down relatively.

Comment: It looks like you're using version 3 which have go over [the fix](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#callout-navbar-fixed-top-padding) for this issue.